# Getting no attribute errors though the function exist for the class in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

Here is the view file where am calling the  method to check password is match But though the method is defined am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'verifyPassword'

**views.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='home',request_method="POST",renderer='templates/index.jinja2')
def homepage(request):
    message=""
    status=""
    if request.params.get('submit'):
        email=request.params.get('email')
        password=request.params.get('password')
        user=UserServices.by_Email(email)
        if user and user.verifyPassword(password):
            status="Success login"

        status="Error Login"
    return dict(
        status=status
```

The function verifyPassword is defined in the model
**models.py** here am just posting the class definition all the necessary imports are done:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    group=Column(Text)

    def verifyPassword(self, password):
        return self.password==password
```

**Here is the script from where I'm getting the user by email:**

```
from ..models import DBSession
from ..models import User

class UserServices(object):
    @classmethod
    def by_Email(cls, email):
        return DBSession.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first()
```

Comment: this looks like a case where you want to learn how to use pdb or the debugtoolbar to step into the code and see what that user object looks like which will likely tell you what's going on